# can't seem to append to a .json array

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, bots, discord

Currently I'm trying to add to a blacklist array for my discord bot. Reading the array works fine, but whenever I try to append to the bot node exits with code 1.

I've tried a few ways, but none really seem to work.

```js
const data = require('./data.json');
data.serverData.blackListedColors.append(randomRoleColor);
```

which returns:

```
                        data.serverData.blackListedColors.append(randomRoleColor);
                                                          ^

TypeError: data.serverData.blackListedColors.append is not a function
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mtutt\OneDrive\Documenten\DiscordKeyBot\bot.js:363:59)
    at Client.emit (events.js:209:13)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\mtutt\OneDrive\Documenten\DiscordKeyBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\mtutt\OneDrive\Documenten\DiscordKeyBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\mtutt\OneDrive\Documenten\DiscordKeyBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\mtutt\OneDrive\Documenten\DiscordKeyBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\mtutt\OneDrive\Documenten\DiscordKeyBot\node_modules\discord.js\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:209:13)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\mtutt\OneDrive\Documenten\DiscordKeyBot\node_modules\discord.js\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:789:20)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:209:13)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've tried using `.parse` and `.add` but those also don't seem to work.

using `.push` doesn't seem to crash it, but also doesn't add the string to the `.json` file.

**edit:**
here's the `.json` file for reference

```
{
  "serverData": {
    "muffinID": "[disocrdID]",
    "token": "[token]",
    "blackListedColors": []
}
```

Comment: data.serverData.blackListedColors is obviousely not an array

Comment: could you post the structure of JSON file, if `data.serverData.blackListedColors` is an array then you can use [Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) else you might need to add a new propoerty and set its value (e.g. `data.serverData.blackListedColors["<newproperty>"] = randomRoleColor`)

Comment: @AkashShrivastava the concat function also doesn't write it into the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `require()` for data that changes during the lifetime of your bot process due to the Node require cache. In addition, just modifying `data` won't automagically persist it back into the file; you'll have to write it back into the file.

It's not rocket surgery to write yourself, but you may want to look into a library that does this for you – I haven't tried this, but it looks promising enough: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-persistent-object

Comment: I tried importing it like:
`
import data from "./data.json"
`

Comment: That's basically the same as `require`in. You'll have to use `fs.readFile`/`fs.writeFile`.

Comment: I tried the json persistent object thing you reccomended, and it worked perfectly using `.push` on the array

Comment: I didn't even need to change the code for it to work, thanks a bunch!